# Unable to select "Enable published model" in LUIS Interactive Testing

Tags: bots, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS application that has been published. When going to the Train & Test section in the portal, I am however unable to select the 'Enable published model' flag on the Interactive Testing tab. The checkbox appears to be active, but nothing happens when I select it.

Thanks,

Pieter

PS: This is also logged on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fde39683-71d0-49e2-b2ef-f4a53f43f7e5/unable-to-select-enable-published-model-in-luis-interactive-testing?forum=LUIS

Comment: Are you using Safari?  We had a report of this on our uservoice forums and are investigating.

Comment: Hi Jim, no, I'm using IE11. It is also not working in Edge, but does appear to be working in Chrome.